# What is the difference is usage between <nav> and <menu> in html5?

Tags: html, markup

What is the difference is usage between nav and menu in html5?

nav or menu, which one?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Straight from the horse's mouth:

http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/interactive-elements.html#menus

> The menu element represents a list of commands.
>
> E.g.:
>
> ```
> <menu label="File">
>    <button type="button" onclick="fnew()">New...</button>
>    <button type="button" onclick="fopen()">Open...</button>
>    <button type="button" onclick="fsave()">Save</button>
>    <button type="button" onclick="fsaveas()">Save as...</button>
> </menu>
> ```

http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/sections.html#the-nav-element

> The nav element represents a section of a page that links to other pages or to parts within the page: a section with navigation links.

Comment: So, analog to "A cow is an animal but an animal is not a cow": a `nav` is a `menu` but a `menu` is not a `nav`?

Answer (score 8):

[`<nav>`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/nav) is a general section of the site layout that holds navigation content

[`<menu>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html-markup-20101019/menu.html) is a list of commands within the navigation or any other layout section